# PDF Access Issues When Saving Files in FileMaker

Tags: adobe, acrobat, filemaker

When I run scripts that save layouts as PDFs in FileMaker Pro v11, the PDFs are not accessible to my colleagues. Adobe opens and tells the user that there was an error and Access was Denied. Is there a way to alter settings, either in FileMaker or Adobe that will allow myself and my colleagues to save records as PDFs in FileMaker so that we will all have access to them?

As a side note, we can Print, choose Adobe as the printer and then save that way with no problem, however the point of the scripts is to make the whole process streamlined to the click of a button. When we use the Print script step so that Adobe is automatically chosen, we still run into the issue of having to manually save, making the 'print' scipt step a non-solution.

Here is the portion of the code that saves the PDF:

```
Save Records as PDF [ File Name: “$folder/$filename”; Current record ] 
[ Document - Compatibility: Acrobat 7 and later ]
[ Pages - Number Pages From: 1; Include: All pages ] 
[ Security - Printing: High Resolution; Editing: Any except extracting pages; Enable copying; Enable Screen Reader ] 
[ Initial View - Show: Page Only; Page Layout: Single Page; Magnification: 100% ]
[ Restore; No dialog ]
```

Comment: The script(s) are not using run with full access privileges- would that have an impact? #Set a variable with the location to save the PDFs. Here is the piece of the code that sets up the folder, name and then saves the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, [Save Records as PDF](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/scripts_ref1.36.71.html):

> Note:  In order to save records as a PDF file, your privilege set must include Allow printing, or you must select Run script with full access privileges in the Edit Script dialog box.

That is,

1. Change the users privelege to allow printing:
   `Manage > Security > Privileges Sets` (and for each set you can check `Allow Printing`).
2. Check "Run the script with full-access privileges" in the edit script page.

I would note, sometimes you may not want users to be able to print everything, and you may not want to run the entire script with full access privileges, so I will offer a third solution:

3. Call a sub-script whose sole purpose is to save as PDF,
check its "Run script with full access privileges" box.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have made a difference. All of our privilege sets allow printing. I checked the "full-access" box and ran the script and none of my other colleagues can open the file. It still says "Access Denied" when they attempt to open the PDF. Is there any other information that I can provide you that may help uncover the solution?

Comment: ah! So the issue is that all users **can save** as a PDF, but once saved only the user who saved it can open it (other users can see it in Finder/explorer, but are unable to open it)? Can I ask where they are saving it and what the permissions are for the file (right-click>get info)?

Comment: So sorry for the delay in response!!! You are correct in your confirmation. All can save, but only the 'saver' can open the file. When I right clicked a PDF I saved and check the security it has a group called Administrators, my self and then a group called SYSTEM listed. All permissions for the groups/user are checked to "allow" Is this what you were asking about? ( I didn't have a 'get info' option, I checked under properties)